# How I Can Use Multi Table for While my data in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I have three tables in mysql (localhost):

1. `customer`, comprising columns `(id,name,email,create_date,status)`;
2. `sell`, comprising columns `(id,s_code,email,dateOut,total_price)`; and
3. `control`, comprising columns `(id,timeIn,timeOut,email,ip)`.

Using a PHP `while` loop, how can I show output from my 3 tables in `<td>` elements?

Comment: 1) write sql query 2) run sql query 3) fetch results in a while loop 4) output results

Comment: Yeah the site is good but your question is not. Nobody knows what you want to achieve.

Comment: Show us your current code. Documentation: [mysqli functions](http://php.net/mysqli)

Comment: But.. what result you want to show?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a query writen to get all rows from your table.

```
 //connect to database  
$dbhost = 'localhost';  
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = '';  
$dbname = 'databasename';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($dbname, $conn) or die ('connection problem');

$html = '';
$sql = "" .
" SELECT * FROM customer, sell, control " .
"";

$data = mysql_query($sql);
if (mysql_num_rows($data) > 0) {
    $html .= '' .
        '<table>' .
        '';
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($data)) {
        $html .= '' .
            '<tr>' .
                '<td>' .
                    '' . //data using tds in table.
                '</td>' .
            '</tr>' . 
        '';
    } //END WHILE
    $html .= '' .
        '</table>' .
        '';
}
echo $html;
```

and that will select all your data inside all your tables in a single query, look through them with the while loop (you should change how the table looks and number of tds) and when its done, it will echo it all out.

good luck. =)

Comment: [All mysql_* functions are deprecated](http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php), don't use them!